# Converting to integer from char buffer in sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

Client Side:

```
char buf[1024];  
int packetAmt = fileSize/PACKETSIZE;
cout<<"Number of packet amounts: "<<packetAmt<<endl; 

// send packet amount to serv
ibytessent=send(s,itoa(packetAmt,buf,10),sizeof(buf),0);
```

Server side:

```
char szbuffer[1024];
if((ibytesrecv = recv(s1,szbuffer,sizeof(szbuffer),0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
     throw "Receive error in server program\n";
cout << "This is the number of packets sent: " << szbuffer << endl;
packetAmt=atoi(szbuffer);
cout << "This is the number of packets sent: " << packetAmt<< endl;
```

The integer returned after converting the char array into integer's doesn't match the string sent. However printing the string will return the correct value.  I have also tried using the strtol function. Could the error occur when converting from integer to char array?

Comment: How close is the number you're getting to what you're expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting 288, but am getting 120 instead.

Comment: That's really odd, especially since you display both the string and the converted value; that implies that `atoi` is totally broken which I refuse to believe. There must be more to it than the code you're showing.

Comment: See [this](http://ideone.com/OgNY12) demo of your program working. How is your `itoa()` implemented?

Comment: I'll check and see if anything else could modify the value, but haven't handled the packet much aside from what was posted on the code above.

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice `288 <===> 0x120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the source of the problem, I had the following line of code which converted the sender's address information into hex values. All the following code had integer values interpreted as hex instead of decimal.

```
cout<<"accepted connection from "<<inet_ntoa(ca.ca_in.sin_addr)<<":"
<<hex<<htons(ca.ca_in.sin_port)<<endl;
```

Thank you for your input, it really helped narrow the problem down!

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` will stop when it reaches the first non-numeric character. If you don't have a terminator in the receiver buffer, it might go past the intended end of the number. It also appears you didn't put a terminator in the sender's buffer either.